# Selector for textboxes in HTML5?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-selectors

Many times with textboxes you can use the selector of "input[type=text]" in the stylesheet or jQuery. Now with all the new textbox variations in HTML5, how can you deal with textboxes besides listing them all out like this?:

> input[type=text], input[type=color], input[type=datetime],
>   input[type=email], input[type=number], input[type=search],
>   input[type=tel], input[type=url],...

Comment: jQuery doesn't currently have a single catch-all pseudo-class for the new HTML5 input types. As it stands jQuery won't have one in the future either, since this issue is marked as "wontfix" in the [jQuery Bug Tracker](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/9132). It's best to create your own selector, as the answers suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no selector that selects those inputs, you can define a custom selector.

```
var types = ['button', 'submit', 'reset', 'hidden', 'checkbox', 'radio'];
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], { 
    textbox: function (elem) {    
       return jQuery.inArray(elem.type, types) === -1
    }
});

$('input:textbox').bar();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xryyq/

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to use just `input` for your textboxes, and then either override (for CSS) or exclude (with `:not()`) to strip out checkboxes, radio buttons, etc.